# Microdot or Flask with Fetch without Then()

Tags: javascript, python

My program works the way I want it to, but I like to understand what I'm doing

Hi,
I opened a discussion on the Micropython forum (https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions/13529) and another on a French Python forum (https://www.developpez.net/forums/d2161662/autres-langages/python/general-python/flask-fetch/) which did not give me a satisfactory answer.
My question is: what does the fetch() command do, without then()?
How does it interact with Flask or Microdot?
Most of the answers were that I should read the documentation, which I did. But I couldn't find anything about this particular case.
The program in question is in micropython/microdot on the first forum and in python/flask on the second.
I think I'm finally on the right forum to have a clear explanation.
Thanks in advance